# Regex pattern matching and its limitations

Tags: regex

I am learning about Regex capabilities, and have a basic understanding of them.

I am now looking into how to use them for pattern matching. One of the things I am not sure about is if they can be used for pattern matching.

I have come accross this specific pattern and am wondering if a Regex would be appropriate to evaluate if the pattern matches?

ABBA

CDDC

DUUD

In the above, the first and last must match, and also the middle 2 - is this the kind of pattern a Regex can be used to match?

If I was to then add these combinations to the patterns above, could a Regex still match it?

ACACR

DJDJB

Again, the pattern here is about items matching at given indexes, so the value at position 0 also appears at position 2?

Is this an appropriate use for a Regex or should I use alternate means.

To be clear, my question is about if a Regex can solve this type of problem, rather other ways to solve it

Comment: @anubhava the entries must match at the same index eg items at index 0 and 4 must be the same for all patterns

Comment: `ACACR` and `DJDJB` can be matched using `^(.).\1.*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are talking about are called [Back References](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html). This is what allows you to build a pattern with a pattern you have previously found.

Your first 2 examples can be matched by this regular expression: `^(.)(.)\2\1$` (example [here](https://regex101.com/r/9MdMLp/1)). In this expression, we are matching the first character and throwing it into a group (we need this so that we can access it later in the pattern matching). We are also doing the same with the second character. We are then instructing the regex engine that on the 3rd character, we are expecting the same value of our second group. This is denoted by `\2` or `$2` in some languages. We are then saying that for the 4th character, we are expecting the same character we have stored in group 1.

You can extend the above to match a sequence of characters which are stored in a group.

For your 3rd and 4th examples, you can build on top of the example above and make it suit your needs.

Comment: how about if I did not know the indexes that had to match, or the length of the pattern?

Comment: @Alex: Do you have an example? In practical cases, you do not base yourself off indexes, but rather into what pattern follows which other pattern. So your example could be interpreted as match a character, match another character, match a character such that it is the same as the second group, match the next character such that it is the same as the first group.

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression cannot detect a [palindrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome) per se, only those with fixed lengths (as in "always 4" or "always 10" characters).

Although it looks rather trivial to have such a feature I yet haven't encountered an implementation that provides such a case. Text editors may have additional flavors such as these:

- `\L` all subsequent characters are in lower case until `\E`
- `\i` outputs a sequence number incremented by 1
- `\p` outputs the clipboard content

...so something like `\R(1)` could also provide the feature "first capture reversed". But as told before: not encountered yet, and unlikely to ever encounter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [backreferences](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) for that. For the first pattern, it would be like '([A-Z])([A-Z])\2\1'.

Comment: how about if I did not know the indexes that had to match, or the length of the pattern?

Comment: I'm going to need an example from you to answer that.